# Query Select Header Join Detail with specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table header :

```
head-id | header-desc
------------------
   1   | Data 1
   2   | Data 2
   3   | Data 3
   4   | Data 4
```

and table detail :

```
detail-id | head-id | detail-desc | category
----------------------------------
   D1     |   1     |      A      |   plant
   D2     |   1     |      B      |   plant
   D3     |   1     |      C      |   plant
----------------------------------
   D4     |   2     |      A      |   plant
   D5     |   2     |      B      |   plant
   D6     |   2     |      E      |   plant
----------------------------------
   D7     |   3     |      A      |   plant
   D8     |   3     |      B      |   plant
   D9     |   3     |      C      |   plant
----------------------------------
   D10    |   4     |      A      |   plant
   D11    |   4     |      B      |   plant
   D12    |   4     |      E      |   plant
```

I want to get data header that consists of elements detail-desc 'A', 'B', 'C'.

I have tried this query, but it returns all data.

```
select count(1), h.head-id from header h 
inner join detail d on h.head-id = d.head-id 
where d.category = 'plant'
and (d.detail-desc like '%A%' or d.detail-desc like '%B%' or d.detail-desc like '%C%')
group by d.head-id
having count(1) = 3;
```

Comment: Your query should return an error because you have no columns names `head` or `id`.

Comment: What's the exact expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a `join` at all.  I would expect something like this:

```
select count(1), d.head_id
from detail d 
where d.category = 'plant' and
      d.detail_desc in ('A', 'B', 'C')
group by d.head_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

Note that no `join` is necessary, because your query requires matches between the tables.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=080e34d5105cac35740499d905c2fa9b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: i have try this, and it still return head-id with detail data 'A', 'B', 'E'

Comment: @D.845574 . . . No, it does not.  Given the data in your question, this appears to do exactly what you want.  I've included a db<>fiddle.  It answers the question.